# How to make RadioButtons work in a Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, radio-button

I want to make RadioButtons work in a ListView. I added a  RadioButton control in the ListView and wrapped it with a LinkButton control. I used the LinkButton in order to use the *ItemCommand* property of the the ListView to change the state of the RadioButton from code Behind.

```
<td>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CommandName="Driver">
             <asp:RadioButton ID="SelectedDriver" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="SelectedDriver_CheckedChanged" />
        </asp:LinkButton></td>
```

To be able to make all radioButton mutually exclusive, I reset all radioButtons in the ListView to *false* then I set the RadioButton that call the event to *true*
Here is the method from code behind:

```
 protected void Drivers_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "Driver")
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem listItem in this.Drivers.Items)
                {
                    (listItem.FindControl("SelectedDriver") as RadioButton).Checked = false;
                }
                (e.Item.FindControl("SelectedDriver") as RadioButton).Checked = true;
            }
        }
```

However it doesn't work as I wanted. when I click on the radioButtons, they keep getting selected none of them get reset. For it to work, I have to add some text beside the radioButton control and I have to click on the text not on the RadioButton for it to work. As you can see the text part is pretty annoying.
Can anyone help me to know what i can do for it to work as intended? Or Does anyone knows a solution that can work.

Thanks

Comment: what do you need the Linkbutton for? Can't you use the GroupName-property of the radiobuttons to group them together and make them mutually exclusive?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. The Radiobuttons are in a ListView

Comment: The radioButtons are just one column in ListView having several columns. Simply using the Groupname property doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the RadioButtons to work as expected, I set the `AutoPostBack = "true"` the property `OnCheckedChanged = "SelectedDriver_CheckedChanged"`

from code behind I did the following and everything works perfectly

```
 protected void SelectedDriver_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton selectedButton = new RadioButton();
            selectedButton = (RadioButton)sender;
            foreach (ListViewItem listItem in this.Drivers.Items)
            {
                (listItem.FindControl("SelectedDriver") as RadioButton).Checked = false;
            }
            selectedButton.Checked = true;
        }
```